# How to create alias to url in Apache 2

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-alias

I have main url like http://apps1.example.com and i want create alias like
http://apps1.example.com/svc-base

in my vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName apps1.example.com

 ProxyPreserveHost On

 ProxyPass / http://123.456.7.8:880/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://123.456.7.8:880/
 
 Alias /svc-base !
 ProxyPass /svc-base http://123.456.7.9:881/

 ProxyRequests     Off
 AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
</VirtualHost>
```

When access from browser the url http://apps1.example.com/svc-base just redirect to main page of http://apps1.example.com/
what's wrong with my code? need advice thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Alias /svc-base !
> ```

Usage for the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive is:
`Alias [URL-path] file-path|directory-path`

An exclamation mark <kbd>!</kbd> is, as far as I know, not a valid syntax for the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive (unless you're actually matching to a file/directory named `/!`).

<sub>(Maybe you're confused with the fact that the exclamation mark <kbd>!</kbd>  can be used in conjunction with a `ProxyPass` directive in situations where you don't want to reverse-proxy a subdirectory and exclude a path that would be otherwise matched by a ProxyPass.)</sub>

What I think you're trying to achieve though, does not require an `Alias` anyway.

---

It appears that you want to `ProxyPass /svc-base` to a different back-end server than the root URL `ProxyPass /`.

That is achieved by changing the ordering of the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directives, as ProxyPass rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So usually you should sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the longest URLs first.

```
 ProxyPass /svc-base http://123.456.7.9:881/
 ProxyPassReverse /svc-base http://123.456.7.9:881/ 

 ProxyPass / http://123.456.7.8:880/
 ProxyPassReverse / http://123.456.7.8:880/
```